# read usb serial code in bash using udevadm

Tags: bash, usb, udev

I am trying to read usb unique id in bash using using udevadm command.
used command is:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdc1
```

output is proper while using a regular usb storage,

```
E: ID_SERIAL=JetFlash_Transcend_2GB_7FYD0N04-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=7FYD0N04
```

But when i use a mp3 player, output is something odd like:

```
E: ID_SERIAL=10d6_USB_2.0_FS__FLASH_DISK_USB_2.0_FS__FLASH_DISK
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=USB_2.0_FS__FLASH_DISK
```

Is there some thing unique other than ID_SERIAL_SHORT for a usb storage?

Thanks

Comment: did you try checking more than one mp3 player? Good luck.

Comment: i tried four usb's and one mp3 player. if this serial is unique then it should be unique for mp3 players too. isn't true?

Comment: with values as shown for your  mp3 player, it is clearly not unique. Maybe something happened to the one you tested OR the manufacture doesn't know what they are doing and other mp3 players are fine. The question is,  do you see similar non-unique values with other mp3 players. if so then you are not lucky. OR as you ask above, maybe there is another value you can query that will be unique. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no unique USB serial numbers. Each vendor selects codes at his own will. There are many devices without USB_SERIAL at all.